# Pass argument to function with case statement

Tags: shell-script, arguments, case

I have this code on my inithome.sh:

```
HOMEDIR="/home/$USER/"

descomu () {
case "$*" in
-ut|--user-tar-dir)
     TARHOMEDIR= "$2"
     if test "$2" = ""
      then
              echo "The direction can't be empty"
              exit
      fi
-p|--permissions
      descomu -p
      ;;
esac

if test "$TARHOMEDIR" = ""
then
      echo "Direction of tar-home not specified. Use -ut or --user-tar-di  r for that."
      exit
else
     if test "$*" = "-p" || test "$*" = "--permissions"
     then
            eval "$( tar -xvfp "$TARHOMEDIR" --directory= "$HOMEDIR" )"
            if "$?" -eq 0
            then
                    echo "Sucess"
                    return 0
            else
                    echo "Fail"
                    return 1
            fi
    else
            eval "$( tar -xvf "$TARHOMEDIR" -C "$HOMEDIR" )"
            if test "$?" -eq 0
            then
                    echo "Sucess"
                    exit
            else
                    echo "Fail"
                    exit
            fi
      fi
fi
}

while test $# -gt 0
do
case $1 in
-ru|--recover-user)
      descomu "$@"
      ;;
*)

      ;;
esac
done
```

I want pass the `-ut` argument value to a variable named `$TARHOMEDIR`, but when I do `./inithome.sh -ru -ut PATH` the `set -u` flag tell me that `$TARHOMEDIR` variable is unassigned. I try with `"$*", "$@", $*` and `"$*"` in `case $foo in` but none worked.

I could make it work with:

```
descomu () {
case "$2" in
-ut|--user-tar-dir)
     TARHOMEDIR= "$3"
     if test "$3" = ""
     then
              echo "The direction can't be empty"
              exit
     fi
-p|--permissions
     descomu -p
     ;;
esac
```

But only work if I have passed only *one* argument in the correct place, but I have more than one argument and I want put them in random places. Is a problem with `IFS` variable? In that case, how I declare him?

Comment: The problem may be a syntactically incorrect space in your assignments.  You cannot use `variable= value`; you must use `variable=value`.

Comment: Also, use `test -z "$var"` to test if a variable is empty, and drop the `eval "$(tar ...)"` for just `tar ...`. You can even use `if tar ...; then`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for the correction about syntax. I have corrected it, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Also infinite loop if you pass something that is not `-ru` or `--recover-user` as the first argument on the command line.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have `if test -z "$#"; then; usage; fi` in my script, and `usage` functions call the documentation :P

Comment: `$#` will never be null.  Even if there are no parameters, it will evaluate to `0`, which is not an empty string.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Oh... I see. I change it to `if test "$#"  -eq 0; then; usage; fi` and worked. Thanks. This is my first script, btw.

Comment: Just a friendly pointer to a good tool: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Kusalananda I used it. And the out are clean :)

Comment: @Moige What is that standalone `-p|--permissions` doing there? Did your sh not cringe?`

Answer (score 3):

Lots of things wrong with the first script.

The `eval` is just wrong, you don't want to execute the output of the tar command!

Each function has its own `$@`, made up of the arguments you call it with, and this also means each function has its own `$1`, `$2`...

you *MUST* not have spaces around the `=` sign in the assignment `TARHOMEDIR="$3"` - it changes the meaning completely.

Normally you would loop over the arguments and process them one at a time, rather than comparing all of the arguments (which is what `$*` is) to particular cases.

As a general rule, you want to use `"$@"` rather than `"$*"`. There are exceptions obviously but they are pretty unusual.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I have replaced `$*` with `"$@"` in `case` statement, remove space bweteen `=` sign, but the problem persisted... Sorry, this is my first script.